# Windows alphabetical file sorting: why do spaces have special treatment?

Tags: windows-10, sorting, filenames

I've noticed that in Windows, when you sort files alphabetically, there's a strange thing that happens when you have file names that extend one another with spaces. For example, say you have two files, "Outline.pdf" and "Outline Revised.pdf". Since the latter has a longer name extending the former, you'd think it would come after. However, when I sort in ascending order, I get:

> Alphabetical.pdf
>
> Outline Revised.pdf
>
> Outline.pdf
>
> Outline_Revised.pdf
>
> Outline-Revised.pdf
>
> Sorting

I've added extra files to illustrate in more detail what is going on. When you have a space between "Outline" and "Revised", the file is sorted before "Outline.pdf"; however, when this space is switched to an underscore or a hyphen, this no longer happens.

My question is: why does Windows treat spaces like this when sorting? I.e., why do spaces take priority over the end of a name?

Less importantly, is there a way to change this?

EDIT: Added file extensions for more context.

EDIT 2: Added more files for a clearer example

Comment: A space in ASCII is 32, as to the reason Windows sorts the way it does, because a Windows developer decided to write the sort that way.  In you example it's not clear if your using ascending or descending.  Without a file extension it's difficult to determine that.

Comment: `Outline` would indeed come before `Outline Revised` but `Outline.` would come after because `.` comes after space. So `Outline.pdf` comes after `Outline Revised.pdf`

Answer (score 8):

Operating systems can really only use one of two basic methods, [ASCII sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) or [Natural sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order)

ASCII gives this

[image]
<sup>pic credit - http://support.ecisolutions.com/doc-ddms/help/reportsmenu/ascii_sort_order_chart.htm</sup>

which takes each single element & applies sort rules, without any other interpretation.

Natural sort attempts to handle such as numerical sequences in a more logical order - so 9, 10, 11 rather than 10, 11, 9
It can also handle more 'library-style' sorting, treating various whitespace characters as equal.

Windows sort would appear to be using ASCII, where space comes before underscore, so sorts first.

You could equally ask, 'Why does windows sort folders to the top with files underneath, when a rational mind would sort naturally?" - someone picked that way, no other reason. Other OSes do sort naturally… which gives issues with such as UUIDs, which ought to be sorted ASCII. There is no perfect solution.

I hadn't included that the example files will have invisible 'dot three' extensions.
The . [dot] will sort after space, ASCII.
*This was before the question was edited to explicitly show the .3*

Empirically, both Mac & Win10 seem to do some kind of natural sort these days - I was sure Windows didn't used to & I don't use Win much so had to have a look.
This is how they each sort the same files…

[image]

They both seem to agree that underscore comes before dash, in contradiction to the strict ASCII sort, but disagree on what to do with the period.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask why "Outline Revised.pdf" sorts before "Outline_Revised.pdf"; I wanted to know why "Outline Revised.pdf" sorts before "Outline.pdf". It can't be because a space comes before a period in ASCII, because "Outline-Revised.pdf" sorts after "Outline.pdf"

Comment: Also, I keep typing "revisited" instead of "revised". Whoops!

Comment: @Sambo, I believe the question is answered, in the list 'space' is at the top and therefore is used before any other character. Period is next, then underscore. In case one, space>. is correct. In case two, period>underscore is correct. Yes?

Comment: @Ack I see what you mean. I didn't think that was the correct reason at first, because when I replaced the space for a hyphen, the hyphen was sorted after the period even though it comes before it in your table. However, with parentheses it sorts it before, so it makes sense that the period is affecting the sorting, which I hadn't realized.

Comment: In short, that table can't exactly be what they're using for sorting. However, you're correct that my error was not taking into account the extension of the file when sorting.

Comment: I've run into this issue because I have an more extreme case of ADD and use symbols to keep my files organized, viewable, and sorted so that I can use them without triggering a rabbit hole. What I found is that there is no consistent system. I had to trial and error to figure out what came before what. Also there are other issues, including that Windows will not allow a leading space in a file name. So, it's confusing to understand, use, ask clear questions and get clear answers. Good luck :) !

Comment: and unicode makes sorting even more difficult.

Comment: Actually, since at least Windows 10 (if not earlier), Windows uses natural sorting, so foo_9.txt does come before foo_10.txt. Or IMG (3).jpg comes before IMG (10).jpg.

Comment: @AplusKminus - yes, I was just doing some testing across Mac & Win. They both appear to do some kind of natural sort… but not in the same way. I'm struggling to pin down the difference precisely. Pic added.

Comment: @AplusKminus: To be precise, Explorer uses natural sorting. On disk, NTFS uses case-insensitive UCS2 sorting, not ASCII. The idea is the same, but more characters are allowed.

Comment: @MSalters Doesn't it do UTF-16 sorting, not UCS2?

Comment: @wizzwizz4: IIRC it doesn't. It sorts the UTF-16 surrogate pairs as if they're two characters.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, but UCS2 doesn't define the surrogate codepoints at all; where does 256 come in the ordering of `char`s? Perhaps “naïve sorting of UTF-16-encoded text”?

Comment: @wizzwizz4: You have to realize that NTFS predates UTF-16. It applies UCS-2 ordering to a `WCHAR[255]` on disk, without regard to the meaning of those `WCHAR`'s. Yes, that means that `U+10001` sorts before `U+FEFF`.