# Windows alphabetical file sorting: is there a way to ignore extensions?

Tags: windows-10, sorting, filenames

(This is a follow-up to [Windows alphabetical file sorting: why do spaces have special treatment?](https://superuser.com/questions/1535169/windows-alphabetical-file-sorting-why-do-spaces-have-special-treatment))

For years I have been confused by the Windows file sorting order; as an example, the pdf file named "Test 1 (Answer Key)" is listed **before** the pdf file named "Test 1" rather than after which would be much more natural (to me, anyway.) It wasn't until I read the answers to the above question that I realized that Windows includes the extensions when doing the sorting, i.e. it looks at the names as "Test 1 (Answer Key).pdf" and "Test 1.pdf, and the space after the 1 in the first name gets prioritized over the period after the 1 in the second name.

Is there any way to tell Windows to ignore the extensions when sorting? I would very much prefer files named like the two above ones to be sorted in the more natural order (obviously without resorting to the extreme solution of sorting in completely reverse alphabetical order.) Ideally I would still like Windows to continue sorting by file type, but just to ignore the extensions when sorting within each type.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can not modify the algorithm used for sort ordering, not unless you have access too, and fancy recompiling certain elements of windows own functionality. If the ordering is really a problem for you, then i'm afraid the only solution left is to explicitly name your files for ordering:
`!Test 1.pdf` or `Test 1 (!Questions).pdf`

Comment: I was afraid of that, just hoping maybe there was a solution I was unaware of. It's more of a recurring annoyance than a problem, certainly not enough to make me rename all my files!