# Windows 11 File Explorer file name sort order - getting a file to the top

Tags: windows, sorting

I'm creating an archive of a web site and within each directory (folder) I have a file called !THE_PAGE_TEXT.html which is basically a readme file for that directory's contents.

I want that to appear at the top of the listing in File Explorer (with, if necessary, clicking on the Name heading).

This [post suggests](https://superuser.com/questions/1535169/windows-alphabetical-file-sorting-why-do-spaces-have-special-treatment) starting with ! should work and it does for me on Win 10 Pro, however for my client with Win 11 Home, it stays at the bottom of what can be a long directory listing.

EDIT
It just occurred to me, the structure of the archive is such that each directory/folder will just contain that one file plus sub dirs, until you get to the last one. So, maybe that's the issue, but it works as I want on Win 10

Comment: Have you sorted the folder by ascending Name order?

Comment: Yes, "Name" was clicked on twice to toggle sort order

Comment: Clicking twice will set the sort order to descending. Click once for ascending.

Comment: What I mean is that it was tried both ways. The other contents was sorted in both directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the underscore `_` at the very beginning of the file name should do the trick, however, folders will always be on top of the listing.

Comment: Thanks, I just came back to edit my question, yes there is just the one file plus folders in the listing. I'll try an underscore then, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome @KevInSol , hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - I've asked my client to try it so will come back here with the results.

Comment: Underscore worked, thanks!